# How do you write the PDE representing the 2 dimensional viscous wave equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

According to [this](https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/35983/Chapter2.pdf) paper, equation 16 says the 1 dimensional viscous wave equation is:

$\frac{4v}{3c_0^2}p_{xxt}+p_{xx}-\frac{1}{c_0^2}p_{tt}=0$

and equation 17 says the 3 dimensional viscous wave equation is:

$\frac{4v}{3c_0^2} \nabla^2  p_{t}+ \nabla^2 p-\frac{1}{c_0^2}p_{tt}=0$

But what does the 2 dimensional viscous wave equation look like?

Comment: Probably just $\frac{4v}{3c_0^2} \nabla^2  p_{t}+ \nabla^2 p-\frac{1}{c_0^2}p_{tt}=0$?

Comment: How does it look like when you expand the gradient operator for two dimensions?

Comment: gradient would be $\binom{\partial_x}{\partial_y}$ and Laplacian is $\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2$?

Comment: So, is this the correct answer for 2 dimensional viscous wave equation : $\frac{4v}{3c_0^2} ( p_{xxt} + p_{yyt})+  p_{xx} + p_{yy}-\frac{1}{c_0^2}p_{tt}=0$  ?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I said

Comment: Ok thanks, if you go ahead and officially answer the question I will mark it as correct.

Comment: One more question. According to this paper: https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220a/handouts/waveequation3.pdf it appears like you need to first go to 3 dimensions and work your way backwards to 2 dimensions.  See section 7.2 (Method of Descent) on page 7/17

Comment: That's probably a very different equation (I know about *this* wave equation, less about the one in your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that in every dimension $1,2,3,\dots$, the answer is just
$$\frac{4v}{3c_0^2} \nabla^2  p_{t}+ \nabla^2 p-\frac{1}{c_0^2}p_{tt}=0$$
where the Laplacian is interpreted correctly for the dimension; $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ in dimension 1, $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$ in dimension 2, $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_2^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_3^2}$ in dimension 3, and so on.